# ProgressBar within my function

Tags: java, android, function

I'm trying to make a progressbar loading within my function. 
I have a function that connect with an external database while load, I need a progressbar.

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/botonAcceder"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_boto_acceptar_intro_cod"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_input_intro_cod"
        android:background="@drawable/fondosubmit"
        android:text="@string/aceptar"
        android:onClick="irFormularioReserva"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_boto_acceptar_intro_cod"/>
```

> ```
>     public void irFormularioReserva(View v){
>
>     /*
>     mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
>     // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
>     new Thread(new Runnable() {
>         public void run() {
>             while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
>
>                 mProgressStatus = thread();
>
>                 // Update the progress bar
>                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
>                     public void run() {
>                         mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
>         }
>     }).start();*/
>
>
>
>     //FUNCIONA NO BORRAR
>     final httpHandler handler = new httpHandler();
>     Thread thread = new Thread()
>     {
>
>         @Override
>         public void run() {
>
>             final String txt = handler.post("http://www.url.com/page.php", "codigo", codigoInput.getText().toString());
>             final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
>             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void run() {
>
>                         //t.setText(txt);
>                         /* #### REDIRECCIÓN A OTRA ACTIVIDAD ##### */
>                         Intent act = new Intent(IntroduceCodigo.this, formularioReserva.class);
>                         act.putExtra("codigo", txt);
>                         startActivity(act);
>                         finish();
>                         /* #### FIN REDIRECCIÓN A OTRA ACTIVIDAD ##### */
>
>
>                     // t.setText(txt);
>                     //System.out.println(txt);
>                 }
>             });
>
>         }
>
>     };
>     thread.start();
> }
> ```

Comment: Look into using an AsyncTask, especially with `onProgress()`.

Comment: what is the issue here..?

Answer (score 0):

As  [323go](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1666116/323go) said. you can use AsyncTask approach which will give you the pre and post stage on network stuff. And easily you can show and dismiss the progressdialog.

```
    class ServerAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //stat the progress dialog
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, message);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Do your server stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //run your progressbar through some time/counter
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //dismiss after finished all server stuffs
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }   

}
```